# Sequence to Sequence Sum Iteration

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, sequence

I'm looking for some direction on how to generate sequences that will have a cumulative sum starting from the end/last of the previous sequence.

The *n_pre* sequence is built from a rolling sum of the original data. The *n_post* sequence needs to build off the *n_pre* sequence's final sum by using the original data values from the correct point in the index.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
data = np.array([10, -1, 10, 10, -1, -10, 5, -5, -5, 10, 10, 5, -10, 10, 5, 10, -5, 10])

# load data into Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['data'])

# perform rolling sum calculation on data
df['roll_sum'] = df.rolling(5).sum().fillna(0)

# prepare data for sequences

X = np.array(df.roll_sum)

Y = np.array(df.data)  # Y array and sequences need to sum the values from the end/last of the n_pre 
sequence

dX, dY = [], []

n_pre = 5
n_post = 3

for i in range(len(X) - n_pre - n_post):
    dX.append(X[i:i + n_pre])
    dY.append((Y[i + n_pre:i + n_pre + n_post]))

dataX = np.array(dX)
#dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (-1, n_pre, 1))
dataY = np.array(dY)
#dataY = np.reshape(dataY, (-1, n_post, 1))
```

The first dataX sequence will generate:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.   0.  28.]
```

The first dataY sequence will generate:

```
[[-10   5  -5]
```

I want the dataY sequence to generate this instead:

```
[[18  23  18]]
```

Which is calculated (from the end of the dataX sequence) 28 -10 +5 -5 = 18 as the final value in that array.

Comment: The question is no clear to me ~

Comment: Are you sure the second two values in `[[18  23  18]]` are correct? I am getting `[[18  33  23]]` Can you do an example calculation of those two as well? I think there might be some missing information OR your output is incorrect. If so, I will update my answer based off what you provide.

Comment: This could also be the corect logic to match your calculation for the first number: `dY.append(a[-1] + sum([i for i in (b)]))` which also outputs 18, but I have no idea how you are getting 23 and 18 for the second and third values.

Comment: Thank you, David, for your help. Unless I'm mistaken in my description, I was calculating the desired dataY first sequence numbers from the final value of 28 at the end of dataX 
 = 28 -10 (=18), 18+5 (=23), 23-5 (=18).

Comment: that makes sense now. Since 18 is the first and last value of that, there was ambiguity. I think I understand the calculation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created variables a, b, c, d and e.

1. c is based off a and b
2. d is based off c and b
3. e is based off d and b
4. We then append c, d, and e per row to `dY` in the for loop per the logic you have defined at the end of your question and in your comment.

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample data
data = np.array([10, -1, 10, 10, -1, -10, 5, -5, -5, 10, 10, 5, -10, 10, 5, 10, -5, 10])

# load data into Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['data'])

# perform rolling sum calculation on data
df['roll_sum'] = df.rolling(5).sum().fillna(0)

# prepare data for sequences

X = np.array(df.roll_sum)

Y = np.array(df.data)  # Y array and sequences need to sum the values from the end/last of the n_pre 

dX, dY = [], []

n_pre = 5
n_post = 3

for i in range(len(X) - n_pre - n_post):
    a = X[i:i + n_pre]
    b = Y[i + n_pre:i + n_pre + n_post]
    c = a[-1] + b[0]
    d = c + b[1]
    e = d + b[2]
    dX.append(a)
    dY.append([c, d, e])

dataX = np.array(dX)
#dataX = np.reshape(dataX, (-1, n_pre, 1))
dataY = np.array(dY)
#dataY = np.reshape(dataY, (-1, n_post, 1))
dataY
```

`dataY` output:

```
array([[18., 23., 18.],
   [13.,  8.,  3.],
   [ 9.,  4., 14.],
   [-6.,  4., 14.],
   [-6.,  4.,  9.],
   [ 5., 10.,  0.],
   [20., 10., 20.],
   [ 5., 15., 20.],
   [20., 25., 35.],
   [30., 40., 35.]])
```